# Linq Categories and SubCategories

Tags: c#, linq

The problem is that I don't understand how to get all Categories and Subcategories with LINQ and add them to list so I can show them in the View.

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I have only this method to get all the categories.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetAllCategories()
    {
        return await _context.Categories.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: output]

Comment: OK forget Linq, and show how you would do it with classical loops... This would be the first step to solve your problem...

Comment: Have you got foreign keys setup in your database? If so, this shouldn't be hard to do it Linq.

Comment: It would be extremely super if you would have created sample data (in valid C# code) to work from.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I start with this data:

```
var categories = new List<Category>()
{
    new Category() { ID = 0, ParentID = null, Title = "First Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 1, ParentID = null, Title = "Second Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 2, ParentID = null, Title = "Third Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 3, ParentID = null, Title = "Fourth Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 4, ParentID = null, Title = "Fifth Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 5, ParentID = 0, Title = "First Child Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 6, ParentID = 0, Title = "Second Child Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 7, ParentID = 0, Title = "Third Child Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 8, ParentID = 6, Title = "First Grandchild Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 9, ParentID = 6, Title = "Second Grandchild Link" },
    new Category() { ID = 10, ParentID = 6, Title = "Third Grandchild Link" },
};
```

...then I can do this:

```
var lookup = categories.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID);
```

That creates a lookup that can be used to find all the children of any parent ID. In your case you should be able to just do `_context.Categories.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID);`. You may need to pop a `.ToArray()` in before the `.ToLookup`.

The nice thing is that this will hit the database only once.

Now it becomes easy to recursively traverse the data. Here are three ways to do it:

(1)

```
Func<ILookup<int?, Category>, int?, int, IEnumerable<string>> formatTree = null;
formatTree = (l, p, i) =>
    from c in l[p]
    from t in new[] { "".PadLeft(i * 4) + c.Title }.Concat(formatTree(l, c.ID, i + 1))
    select t;
```

(2)

```
public IEnumerable<string> FormatTree(ILookup<int?, Category> lookup, int? parent, int indent)
{
    return
        from c in lookup[parent]
        from t in new[] { "".PadLeft(indent * 4) + c.Title }.Concat(FormatTree(lookup, c.ID, indent + 1))
        select t;
}
```

(3)

```
public IEnumerable<string> FormatTree2(ILookup<int?, Category> lookup, int? parent, int indent)
{
    foreach (var category in lookup[parent])
    {
        yield return "".PadLeft(indent * 4) + category.Title;
        foreach (var descendant in FormatTree2(lookup, category.ID, indent + 1))
        {
            yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

All three do the same thing in the same way just with different syntax.

I get this output:

```
First Link 
    First Child Link 
    Second Child Link 
        First Grandchild Link 
        Second Grandchild Link 
        Third Grandchild Link 
    Third Child Link 
Second Link 
Third Link 
Fourth Link 
Fifth Link
```

It's not clear what you exact output is - I assume you don't want a PNG image created - but you should be able to work with that to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical tree structures are not really suited for running LINQ queries, as you *(unfortunately)* need to expand your query for each level of hierarchy you want to include.

This query should give you all top-level categories as groups with their direct children:

```
var query = from category in _context.Categories
            where category.ParentID == null
            from subCategory in _context.Categories
            where subCategory == category.ID
            group subCategory by category;
```

If you only have two levels of hierarchy, this should work fine, but to really get a tree structure in any kind of order, you need to flatten the hierarchy, and that is typically done using a recursive function, where every call to it *(by itself)* flattens one node of the tree.

For this kind of structure, standard SQL queries or LINQ queries don't really cut it. However, Entity Framework *(and probably other ORM solutions as well)* will do all the work for you.

You could create a couple of properly attributed navigation property in your model, something like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
```

But if you choose to **not** include navigation properties in your model, you need to do this the hard way, making requests to your data layer for every call to the recursive function.

```
public void RenderSubCategoriesAsHtml(int? parentID = null)
{
    var children =
        from category in _context.Categories
        where category.ParentID == parentID
        select category;

    if (children.Any())
    {
        Response.WriteLine("<ul>");
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            Response.WriteLine("<li><a href=\"#addProperUrl\">");
            Response.WriteLine(Server.EncodeHtml(child.Title));
            Response.WriteLine("</a>");
            RenderSubCategoriesAsHtml(child.ID);
            Response.WriteLine("</li>");
        }
        Response.WriteLine("</ul>");
    }
}
```

Just change the calls to `Response.WriteLine` into what is more suited for your application's architecture.

Comment: Thanks I think i got idea from what you've said and it might be better if I try with recursive function.

Comment: I would not say that standard SQL have problem with it, as recursive query is perfectly standard. The problem may be on the side of ORM.

Comment: Perfectly standard? How would you solve it without `cross apply`?

Comment: I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing, I was talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: I just got up with something strange, and I don't really know why is that happnenig, when both methods should achiev the same thing. So the thing is when I use: `var children =
        from category in _context.Categories
        where category.ParentID == parentID
        select category;` gives me diffrent result than using this: `var categories = await _context.Categories.Include(a => a.Parent).Where(p=>p.ParentID == null).ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

EF has a way of doing that. But you have to have a foreign key relationship between `Category` and `Subcategory`

```
var all categoriesWithSubCategories =  _context.Categories.Include("Subcategory").ToList();
```

Now when you select a category from `categoriesWithSubCategories` list, you will have access to all subcategories belong to the selected category.

**Adding more details to explain further;**

As I mentioned before you have to have a FK relationship on the Same table to do this.

That means your `ParentId` field has a foreign key relationship to your `Id` field, which is your PK field.

Now change your entity class slightly to represent the above relationship.

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.SubCategory = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Once that's done, all you need is a single line of Linq (above) to build a perfect tree hierarchy for your Categories and Sub Categories.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a great way of doing this!

Comment: @AndersTornblad `great way of doing` what? when  the name of `Subcategory` is not available...

Comment: I have added more details to my answer. Hope that will explain why `SubCategory` (or SubCategories) is required.